# Conditional Rendering not responding in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, conditional-statements

I am having trouble with my conditional statement. It only ever renders true even when it is false. I have a jobs list page that when pressed sets the 'selectedJob.' That job is then presented in a modal where you can save the job or remove it. But if the job is already been saved then I need the correct button to be displayed.

```
  const [saved, setSaved] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSaved(selectedJob.saved);
  }, [selectedJob]);

            {saved ? (
              <Button
                onPress={() => removeJob(selectedJob)}
                btnTxt={"Saved"}
              />
            ) : (
              <Button
                onPress={() => saveJob(selectedJob)}
                btnTxt={"Save"}
              />
            )}
```

Comment: What is the value of `selectedJob.saved`?

Comment: I just found something strange. I changed my server to output '' instead of 'false' and it began to work? Not sure why this happened.

Comment: share full code for more info regarding `selectedJob`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use boolean as a string like `'true'` and `'false'` it compares as string not boolean so as long as it's value is not `null` or `undefined` or `''` it will be considered as true so either you should change your server to use boolean values instead of string or you can match string in condition like

```
        {saved == 'true' ? (
          <Button
            onPress={() => removeJob(selectedJob)}
            btnTxt={"Saved"}
          />
        ) : (
          <Button
            onPress={() => saveJob(selectedJob)}
            btnTxt={"Save"}
          />
        )}
```